# Interaction in epub and iBooks

Tags: html, ios, macos, epub, ibooks

I have a simple epub with html inputs like this:

```
  <p> Input - type tel: 
    <input type="tel" value="20"/>
  </p>

  <p> Input - type text: 
    <input type="text" value="hola"/>
  </p>
```

Both inputs are disabled in iBooks for iOS and Mac. In [Looking for ibooks html input alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604869/looking-for-ibooks-html-input-alternative), we can find a trick to enable the html inputs in iOS, but it is not ok in Mac.

Do you know an easy way to enable the interaction with html inputs in iBooks for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that html `<input type="text" />` works well in iBooks, at least in what I call "popup" pages. It's just a page that you define as `linear="no"` in the OPF Spine section. Then when you'll click on a link to this "popup", the "popup" will... pop up? Yes!...

Anyway, the design and functionnalities of "popups" is not the same as the classical "flow layout" of the rest of your standard EPUB pages, so maybe that's why it could work there.